# div element takes extra vertical space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a contact us page. the heading here takes only the intended space but the div takes up extra vertical space. Where did I go wrong?

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 99vw;
  height: 96vh;
  padding-top: 4vh;
}

#heading {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0.7em;
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="heading">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="media_container">
    <img class="soc_med" src="fb.png" alt="fb">
    <img class="soc_med" src="instagram.png" alt="insta">
    <img class="soc_med" src="linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn">
    <img class="soc_med" src="email.png" alt="email">
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you setting the height of the section `96vh`? This means that the contact page section would always be 96% of the original height of the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the height from the `section`

```css
section{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: 99vw;
      padding-top: 4vh;
    }
    
    #heading{
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 0.7em;
    }
    
    h1{
      display: inline;
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 1rem;
    }
```

```html
<section>
      <div id = "heading">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
      </div>
      <div id = "media_container">
        <img class="soc_med" src="fb.png" alt="fb">
        <img class="soc_med" src="instagram.png" alt="insta">
        <img class="soc_med" src="linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn">
        <img class="soc_med" src="email.png" alt="email">
      </div>  
    </section>
```

Comment: It worked! Why does it behave this way though?

Comment: When you remove,it will set `height-auto`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin: 0;` to `html, body` to avoid the default  margins on these elements which are the cause for your problem:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 99vw;
  height: 96vh;
  padding-top: 4vh;
}

#heading {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0.7em;
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="heading">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="media_container">
    <img class="soc_med" src="fb.png" alt="fb">
    <img class="soc_med" src="instagram.png" alt="insta">
    <img class="soc_med" src="linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn">
    <img class="soc_med" src="email.png" alt="email">
  </div>
</section>
```